# How to use LIKE SQL query in JS RESTFUL api?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Trying to make a search query for mySQL with JS.

Working code:

```
    searchRestaurants(request, respond){
        var term = request.params.id
        var sql = "SELECT restaurant FROM restaurant_details WHERE restaurant LIKE '%' ? '%'";
        db.query(sql, term, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my code: (old)

```
"use strict"

var db = require("../db-connection");

class RestaurantDB{
    searchRestaurants(request, respond){
        var key = request.params.id
        var sql = "SELECT restaurant FROM restaurant_details WHERE restaurant LIKE '% ? %'";
        var values = [key];
        db.query(sql, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = RestaurantDB;
```

Id is received through user input through url.

```
"use strict"

const restaurantdb = require("../models/RestaurantDB");

var restaurantDBObject = new restaurantdb();

function routeRestaurants(app){
    app.route("/restaurant")
        .get(restaurantDBObject.getAllRestaurants);
    app.route("/restaurant/:id")
        .get(restaurantDBObject.searchRestaurants)
}

module.exports = {routeRestaurants};
```

So when I try going to "localhost:8080/restaurant/way" to try and search for Subway, it returns nothing. Just a "[]".
What is the correct way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance

Here's a working example

```
    addReview(request, respond) {
        var now = new Date();
        var reviewObject = new Review(null, request.body.restaurant, request.body.rating, request.body.comment,
            request.body.username, now.toString());
        var sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (restaurant, rating, comment, username, timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

        var values = [reviewObject.getRestaurant(), reviewObject.getRating(),
        reviewObject.getComment(), reviewObject.getUsername(), reviewObject.getTimestamp()];

        db.query(sql, values, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            else {
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

db-connection

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    port:"3306",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"project"
});
module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: The answer to your question depends entirely on what mysql module you're using in nodejs. Could you provide this information in your question?

Comment: The `?` in `'% ? %'` is handled as a literal question mark rather than parameter place-holder. You also define `values` and never use it. I suspect you just need to be more careful with syntax.

Comment: @ÉvelyneLachance I'm using RESTFUL api, not sure if that's what you are asking though.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I added a working example where the ?s are replaced by the values variable. That's what I'm trying to achieve with this statement. Would you know the correct syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Please mind the quotes. `?` is different from `'?'`, just like `null` is different from `'null'` and `restaurant` is different from `'restaurant'`.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're not *using* an API, you're *making* one. This is indicated by your use of nodejs (server-side programming), what appears to be express.js routes, as well as... well, actual SQL statements which are not possible if it's not server-side. So, the question still stands, in your `db-connection` file, what is the mysql module you're importing or requiring?

Comment: @ÉvelyneLachance seems like it's uh.. mysql? Added my db-connection into the post. Thanks

Comment: In searchRestaurants, you're settling values, but not passing them to db.query

Comment: Thanks everyone, figured it out. Had to change the syntax and add the value into the query.